# What do irreducible closed subsets of a variety look like?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. For any $k-$variety, $V$, let $t(V)$ denote the set of all irreducible, closed subsets of $V$. Irreducible here means that a set $V$ cannot be written as a union of two closed subsets of $V$.

Is my claim, $$t(V) = \{\{p\}^-\mid p\in V\}$$ correct?

Here, $S^-$ denotes the closure of the set in $V$. Is it correct to assume that not all points of a $k$-variety are closed?

**I think this is true** because if $F\in t(V)$ is closed and irreducible, then it is a subset of $V$, say $F = \bigcup \{q\}$ for some $q\in V$. If we take the closure on both sides, we get $$F = \bigcup \{q\}^-$$ and if there is any $q,r$ such that their closures are not equal to $F$, then clearly, I can write $F$ as a union of closed subsets (as $F\cap \{q\}^- = \{q\}^-$ is closed in $F$)

Thus, we must have, for all $q$ in $F$, that $\{q\}^- = F$ which shows $$t(V) \subset\{\{p\}^-\mid p\in V\}$$

The other inclusion holds as $\{p\}^-$ is clearly closed and also irreducible as $\{p\}$ is a singleton and thus irreducible.

Comment: By 'variety' do you mean a $k$-scheme with some properties or a variety 'in the classical sense' as a subset of $k^n$ whose points satisfy some polynomial equations? In the first case the claim is correct (in every scheme any irreducible subset admits a (unique) generic point), in the latter case it is not true: then every point is closed. Note that in your proof the union might be infinite, so we cannot conclude $F=\overline{\{q\}}$ for some $q\in F$.

Comment: Oh, I see! I really missed the statement about arbitrary unions.